# Alert is not visible in nativescript ios after autocomplete usage

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-plugin

I am working on a nativescript app for android and ios in which I have used REST APIs to store/get data in JSON format.
Based on JSON result from APIs sometime I need to show alert to the user.
It was working fine with Nativescript 4.1 but since I have upgraded to 4.2 app is unable to show alert boxs in ios. It shows the blank page and shows the following error.

```
(UIKitCore) Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7fb5834eb000> on <UIViewControllerImpl: 0x7fb58659a670> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

I have suspected that I am calling alert too early so I have tried to add timeout before alert but still it's the same.

```
if (result.status === 'E') {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    const alertOptions = { title: 'Error', message: result.errMsg, okButtonText: 'OK', cancelable: false };
                    dialogs.alert(alertOptions).then(() => {
                        resolve('Error');
                    });
                }, 700);
```

Points to note here is I am using [nativescript-autocomplete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-ui-autocomplete) component in one of my tabs. and this problem occurs only when user searches something using that component.
So it could be something related to that component.May be when autocomplete closes the modal, app looses the parent reference ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an interim solution for now.
[nativescript-fancyalert](https://github.com/NathanWalker/nativescript-fancyalert) works like a charm. Will stick with that for sometime.
It is based on [SCLAlertView](https://github.com/dogo/SCLAlertView) for ios.

Comment: There was a known issue with alerts on iOS that it won't appear if you don't have a frame in your application. It was fixed in 4.2 I believe not sure what is still stopping you. If you like to debug this further, please share the playground example where the issue can be reproduced.